# Are "Is it just me?" questions on-topic on SO?

Tags: discussion

Are questions which are basically only asking if it is just me on-topic on SO (or on some other SE site)?

I have had a couple problems with IDEs and libraries recently and I honestly wanted to know if a problem was just occurring on my machine or my version of the tool or if it was actually a widespread problem.

I understand that if I search for the problem and nothing shows up chances are it's a local problem but some of this stuff is pretty niche.

Can I ask such a question here.

Comment: Contacting the IDE support should be your first option.

Comment: Ahm...sorry for that close vote...I kinda hit the button before reading halfway through...

Comment: @Oded In this case I put in a ticket on chromium

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: You can retract CVs these days. Open the dialog again and click the 'retract' button.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks, didn't know about that, that's pretty neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are questions about IDEs on-topic? Well, kinda. Are questions about problems with IDEs on-topic? Well, depends. But are questions about if you're the only one which has problems on-topic? That's a clear no.

We do questions about IDEs. That ranges from basic stuff (okay, someone else who actually wants to close those?) to problems, errors and complex and complicated situations and limitations. So if you have a problem with your IDE, I'd start to use the following checklist:

- Search appropriate pages, bugtrackers and forums
- Search the internet
- Think really really really hard if you can't solve the problem
- Contact the appropriate support people for the IDE (especially if you paid money for it, after all you already paid them and got something that's not working)
- Repeat these steps at least twice (three times would be better)
- Ask about it on Stack Overflow

We don't need every possible instance of "why is IDE y complaining that library x is missing?" or "why is IDE z doing this? - It's a bug, patched long ago." on SO.

If you think you found a bug, it would be more appropriate to report it to devs instead of asking here how to circumvent or fix it. But if you have a problem all these people along these steps could not solve, I think we will be happy to accept a good question on it.